# initial state lstm encoder decoder keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I am trying to build an LSTM encoder decoder where my main goal is that the inital state of the decoder is the same as the encoder. I found the code below from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/#comment-437996) and tried to attach it to my case. I have a data with shape (1000,20,1). I want that the encoder decoder gives me in the output my input back. I do not know how to correct the code that it is working, even I understand the error. When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
The model expects 2 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: 
array with shape (10000, 20, 1)




from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

latent_dim = 128
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(20,1))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(20, 1))
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(1, activation='tanh')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['acc', 'mae'])

history=model.fit(xtrain, xtrain, epochs=200, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

I also have this model, but I am not sure how I can initalize here the encoder state same as the decoder state. Is the repeatvector doing this ?

```
#define model

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(n_timesteps_in, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_timesteps_in))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features, activation='tanh')))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

history=model.fit(train, train, epochs=epochs, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building a model with 2 inputs, namely `encoder_inputs` and `decoder_inputs` but only giving one input `.fit(xtrain, xtrain, ...)` the second argument is the output. In case you need to give another argument of the form `.fit([xtrain, the_inputs_for_decoder], xtrain, ...)`

Comment: Well that depends on how you pre-process your data, what are you are trying to achieve etc, you will have to define the your inputs for your decoder just as you defined `xtrain`. Simply, your model expects another input which you need to give as a list `[enc_inputs, dec_inputs]`

Comment: from where do I define the inputs_for_decoder ? Does not the model automatically define this input to the decoder ?

Comment: I just know the lstm encoder decoder has to predict the same data therefore xtrain, xtrain. but I cant figure out how to define the dec_inputs. I mean cant I say the model encode the input and take this as input for the decoder ? it does not make sense for me or I do understand it at all. Besides it is important the the encoders inital state is the same with the one from the decoder. Maybe you have an example for me how to fix this ?

Comment: If you give the same input for the decoder, then it will just learn identity! Your code was designed to do teacher forcing which only works if the sequences are different. What are you after is seq2seq auto-encoders, have a look at [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) or [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9093).

Comment: I updated my post with an additional code, this is also a seq2seq autoencoder. But I do not know if the inital state of encoder and decoder are the same. is the repeatvector doing this ?